# Server getting slower over time

Tags: php, apache, centos

I am using a dedicated server for my PHP application. Server slowing down day by day after a reboot everything goes normal. I cache my json results as files and serve them to clients when everything normal response time is about 50ms but when server slows down response time goes up to 17 seconds or more.

This issue affects all server, I can't even login with ssh when this happens.

I don't have enough knowledge about servers.

How can I track this problem?

System Up for 6 Days now, and slowing down started again -

Here are my results

```
 # lsof | wc -l
 34255

 # free
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:       32641048     1826832     6598216      232780    24216000    29805868
Swap:      16760828           0    16760828
```

My Server has 32gb Ram, 8 Core cpu, Centos 7. 
I run a laravel application with 500 unique users daily. 
I restarted MySQL service, httpd service, ngnix service, and cleared memory cache, nothing changed. Only the server reboot helps.

Static files response normally, but files served by PHP application or HTTP responses very slow and getting slower day by day.

Login with ssh getting slower too, I use plesk as control panel but it is getting slower too.

I mean this problem affects not only my application but all server.

Comment: Are you tables properly indexed and normalized...  Do you have any offsite resources like Google Fonts etc.  I had a slow site because of some google fonts.. lol  ... You should start by doing some bench marking on slow parts of the stie, no point adjusting things tell you get that baseline.

Comment: Have you tried checking the running processes?